# How can I use Python to split a series of strings in a database and then pivot the result showing the word and the count of times it appears

Tags: python, split, nlp, word-count

If I have a database with 100s of thousands of separate string combinations with an easy separator like,

how can I split the string of each dimension and then get a count by word in a column output?

I am new to python so I understand a simple split and basics of DF setups but I am not sure how to put it all together.

For example, how the following works but I am not sure I would loop through all those strings that I have? seems like it would be done a different way and how would I then count the result of all of it.

```
txt = "word1 | word 2 | word 3 | etc "

x = txt.split()

print(x)
```

Any help including a resource in where to learn more about basics of what I am doing will be helpful.

Comment: If you only want to get the number of items separated by `' | '` in `txt`, then you can simply do this: `words_count = txt.count(' | ') + 1`

Answer (score 0):

A good approach will be using Pandas.

load your DataBase to a pandas DataFrame and use the string command.

Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"words":["word1 | word 2 | word 3 | etc", "word 4 | word 5"]})

                           words
0  word1 | word 2 | word 3 | etc
1                Word 4 | Word 5
```

and to split the values:

```
result = df.words.str.split("|", expand=True)
result
         0         1         2     3
0   word1    word 2    word 3    etc
1  word 4     word 5      None  None
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, we have a data structure named as a dictionary. Here, we have a key-value pair where the value stores information related to the key. Read more about it from here - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

There is a shortcut method to get count of strings:

```
from collections import Counter
words = txt.split('|)
counts = Counter(words)
```

Now, the dictionary `counts` stores string and how many time it appears. To get the frequency of a string say `'word 1'`, you need to write `counts['word 1']`. Please feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: There are potentially thousands of different words. is there a way to do this where the counts['word1'] can be automated?

I need to split them and then pivot the aggregated total of each word so my index is the word and column is the sum of the word.

Comment: to expand a little further  
  
I am working with many strings that I need to relate to each other  
So if in one string i have "Jim1 | word 2 | word 3 | etc"  
and in another I have " Jim1 | word 1| word 2"  I need to be able to select Jim in a later  
SQL to return the aggregate of the words that appears when Jim1 appeared.  "Word 1" appeared once and "word 2" appeared twice and "word 3" appeared once  
I know there will be multiple steps but adding this context might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways of getting a count, for example:

```
 x = len(txt.split("|"))
```

but split is not required, you can just count separators + the first element:

```
txt.count("|") + 1
```

Comment: This would give me a count of words per string path correct?